# Kde manjaro проблема с автозапуском

Tags: manjaro, kde, автозапуск

Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Имеется сервер, на котором стоит базовый образ manjaro kde. Установлена прога для удаленного доступа к графической среде. Проблема заключается в том, что прога стартует исключительно после логина. Из sddm подключиться не выходит. Автозапуск стоит одновременно и из графической среды (стандартными средствами) и через  `systemctl enable current.service`. Оба способа срабатывают здесь только после входа пользователя.   Каким образом в kde можно настроить автозапуск, чтобы программа стартовала после запуска системы, а не после логина пользователя?

Upd. В настоящее время .desktop файл автозапуска существует по пути $Home/.config/autostart

Upd.2
Основной сервис (current.service) имеет следующую конфигурацию:

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/anydesk.service
[Unit]
Description=AnyDesk
Requires=network.target
#After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/anydesk --service
PIDFile=/var/run/anydesk.pid
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=30
User=root
LimitNOFILE=100000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй включить linger для пользователя на сервере:

```
loginctl enable-linger <username>
reboot
```

что позволит сервису **current.service** запускаться при запуске сервера, а не при входе пользователя. Это конечно если сам **current.service** настроен на запуск от пользователя.

```
man loginctl
...
enable-linger [USER...], disable-linger [USER...]

    Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a 
    specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept 
    around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run 
    long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as 
    argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering 
    for the user of the session of the caller.
```

Comment: К сожалению такой способ не срабатывает. Использовал команду для текущего пользователя loginctl enable-linger $USER

Comment: @ar-rr, покажите свой сервис: `systemctl cat current.service`

Comment: Предположение о том, что необходимо убрать часть "After" - не сработало

Comment: @ar-rr, там ничего не понять, а разбирать этот завал лень, добавьте вывод `systemctl cat current.service` в свой основной вопрос отредактировав его.

Comment: @ar-rr, в строке `User=root` поменяйте имя суперпользователя рут(root) на имя пользователя под кем нужно запускать сервис. ... Хотя стоп, судя по названию у вас приложение Anydesk (The Fast Remote Desktop Application). Забудте про `current.service` и даже расскоментируйте то что вы закоментировали там ранее. Вам для правильной работы этой программы нужно настроить автовход(автологин) в графическую оболочку пользователя, не загрузку данного сервиса который можно поднять и без графической оболочки, а именно старт после загрузки рабочего стола КДЕ.

Comment: @ar-rr, то есть вам нужно чтобы при старте сервера с Kde manjaro у вас происходил автологин выбранного пользователя, а это настраивается в настройках самой системы, поищите там.

Comment: @ar-rr, вот кстати на форуме манджары есть тема про то как отключить автологин в sddm - https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sddm-autologin-override/65331 -- `Go to System settings → Startup and Shutdown → Login Screen (SDDM) and find on the bottom Behavior button and uncheck autologin.` ну а вам нужно наоборот включить его.

Comment: Автологин я нашел, он работает. Но это не то, чего хотелось бы добиться. Такая проблема как-то связана с оболочкой, поскольку на Gnome в gtk3 после включения через systemctl сервис работает.

Comment: @ar-rr, то есть вам нужно чтобы anydesk стартовал при загрузке менеджера входа(SDDM) но до логина пользователя ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136604/discussion-between-ar-rr-and-zt).

Comment: @ar-rr,  если хотите сменить менеджер входа в систему с sddm на gdm то это делается примерно так: `sudo pacman -S gdm ; sudo systemctl disable sddm.service; sudo systemctl enable gdm.service; sudo reboot`